# Не открывается файл на чтение Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, phpexcel

Работаю с библиотекой PHPExcel в Wordpress нужно прочесть данные из excel файла, взял отсюда - https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpexcel 
Получаю ошибку

Fatal error: Uncaught PHPExcel_Reader_Exception: Could not open http://uh214936.ukrdomen.com/barsa/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/u-14-1.xlsx for reading! File does not exist

Выглядит будто нет файла но файл есть и он скачивается без проблем. У меня единственная мысль по этому поводу на сервере стоят права запрещающие чтение файлов. 
Что посоветуте? 
Вот здесь детальней можете гялнуть ошибку - http://uh214936.ukrdomen.com/barsa/media/no-products/u-14/

Собственно на второй строке и ошибка

```
$file = get_field('excel_file_standings_table'); //получаем ссылку на файл

$phpExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file['url']); //загружаем файл на чтение через библиотеку
```

Распечатал путь к файлу получилось так

```
http://uh214936.ukrdomen.com/barsa/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/u-14-1.xlsx
```

Это абсолютный путь к файлу.

Comment: Покажите код, которым файл открываете. Мы ж не телепаты)

Comment: Добавил, на второй строчке код умирает, что еще нужно прикрепить?

Comment: А выведите `$file['url']`. Там абсолютный или относительный путь?

Comment: Распечатал путь к файлу

Comment: Я думал проблема в библиотеке но нет протестил на локалке все норм, правда тежстил не в среде вордпресс да и на ОС Виндовс. Поэтому отличия есть

Comment: Вы зачем в имени файла указываете `http://`? Так работать не будет. Надо `/home/uh214936/domains/uh214936.ukrdomen.com/public_html/barsa/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/u-14-1.xlsx`

Comment: То есть вы должны указать внутренний файловый путь на сервере.

Comment: Библиотека умеет только с локальными файлами работать, насколько я помню.

Comment: Парни спс за помощь все получилось :)